# Actualizar a varios registros

Tags: sql, update

> Quiero actualizar todos los registros de una tabla (tbl_DepresacionesUmas) donde el estatus sea diferentes a baja pero al hacer eso por consecuencia me regresa mas de un valor y me genera un erro como puedo solucionar eso en sql?

```
    Update Tbl_DepresacionesUmas
set ValorActual =ValorInicial
where Estatus != 'Baja'

Update Tbl_DepresacionesUmas
set Dias = ( DATEDIFF(Day,Fecha_Inicio, GETDATE()))
where Estatus != 'Baja'
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema con tu código actual. Obviamente es mejor hacerlo en un solo `UPDATE`, pero no te debería generar error

Comment: @Lamak el error es que me devuelve mas de un valor en el where y no me permite hacer los calculos por ejemplo en dias en el set

Comment: que error es el que te genera ?

Comment: Nos ayudarias compartiendo el error que te genera @JT25

Comment: por lo que vi en otras paginas,al devolverme muchos valores en el estatus se batalla en obtener la fecha de inicio en el calculo de dias debido por el id que no tiene con cual compararlo porque son muchos

Comment: Es que no entiendo por qué te lanzaría algún error, es una operación que se hace fila a fila

Comment: lo unicos posibles errores que puedo llegar a ver serua que en campo `Dias` no este recibiendo un valor adecuado en el `Update` o que Estatus no tenga tipo varchar

Comment: Agradeceriamos si nos apoyas con la estructura de la tabla Tbl_DepresacionesUmas y algunos registros.

Comment: primero que todo debemos ver que esta obteniendo la variable `ValorInicial` debe estar tomando mas de un valor, es por eso el problema de la actualización. hay que revisar primero esa variable. pega el código completo...

Comment: podria ser que el error lo estes teniendo en otro query y no en el update

Answer (score 0):

ya probastes con la siguiente manera

```
 Update Tbl_DepresacionesUmas
set ValorActual =ValorInicial,
Dias = ( DATEDIFF(Day,Fecha_Inicio, GETDATE()))
where Estatus != 'Baja';
```

Comment: el problema sigue siendo que me devuelve mas de un valor en estatus por que me devuelve muchas bajas,lo estoy realizando en un procedimiento almacenado

Comment: @JT25 pero cuál es el problema de que devuelva más de un valor?

Comment: que el id del registro para sacar la fecha de inicio en el calculo de dias no lo puedo comparar con un registro de los que me devuelve en la condicion que sea diferente a estatus baja porque me devuelve mas de uno

Comment: lo que comente arriba, entonces pon todo el procedimietno almacenado que tiene

Comment: @JT25 es que entonces no has explicado la lógica del resultado que quieres. Y por otro lado, no es que arroje error, es que no te está entregando lo que tienes pensado, que es diferente

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera, actualizaras de acuerdo al ciclo que estés usando cada registro que cumpla con la condición:

```
UPDATE Tbl_DepresacionesUmas
SET ValorActual = ValorInicial, Dias = (DATEDIFF(DAY,Fecha_Inicio, GETDATE()))
WHERE Estatus NOT IN ('Baja');
```

Comment: El problema no esta en la sintaxis.. el query no actualiza porque una de las variables esta tomando mas de un valor...

Comment: exacto lo que nesito es una solucion para que compare un id con el otro

Comment: si dejas las tablas aquí podría ayudarte mejor y una mejor explicación de lo que quieres ya que no se entiende mucho